# Can I ask a historical question?

Tags: discussion

I spend most of my SE time on [MO](http://mathoverflow.com), where historical questions are usually shunted aside to [HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).  Are historical questions appropriate here?

Specifically, I want to know why (if anyone but Girard knows!) linear and affine types are so called.  (That is, what about their resource limitation is particularly linear, or affine?)  Is that an appropriate question for CStheory, or is there an HCStheory-type site where I should ask instead?

Comment: I asked the same question at [LtU](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/5316#comment-94550), and found the discussion there very enlightening.  Accordingly, it seems that I no longer need to ask here, but thanks to [@LevReyzin](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2977/28535) for responding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, I think historical questions could be okay if they are of interest to researchers.